# if daemon threads have low priority how it runs before all user threads completes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read daemon threads are low priority threads and it runs only when no other user threads are alive. But the below code does not have any difference.

```
public class DaemonThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DaemonThread d = new DaemonThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(d,"daemon");
        t1.setDaemon(true);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(d,"Non-Daemon"); 
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("Main finished");
    }}
    class DaemonThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ i);
        }
    }}
```

And the output is,

```
Main finished
Non-Daemon0
Non-Daemon1
Non-Daemon2
Non-Daemon3
Non-Daemon4
Non-Daemon5
Non-Daemon6
Non-Daemon7
daemon0
daemon1
daemon2
daemon3
daemon4
daemon5
daemon6
daemon7
daemon8
daemon9
Non-Daemon8
Non-Daemon9
```

Comment: Daemon threads stop their execution if all the other user thread stop executing. Daemon threads run only when other user threads are running. That's the concept of Daemon threads. Just because a thread has a lower priority, doesn't mean it will never run, as such situation will lead to starvation.

Comment: What you've read is wrong. Daemon threads does not have lower priority than other threads. Your threads also sleep(), the threads are not running when they're sleeping. If a high priority thread is not running, a low priority thread can run - so this code does not test your claims.

Answer (score 0):

Threading priorities are largely handled by the operating system and so it plays a big part in deciding when to allow Threads to run.  For example I ran your code a couple of times and on one run I got this output:

```
Main finished
daemon0
daemon1
daemon2
daemon3
daemon4
daemon5
daemon6
daemon7
daemon8
daemon9
Non-Daemon0
Non-Daemon1
Non-Daemon2
Non-Daemon3
Non-Daemon4
Non-Daemon5
Non-Daemon6
Non-Daemon7
Non-Daemon8
Non-Daemon9
```

Which is almost a complete reverse to your results.  Whilst you can try setting priorities manually it will still ultimately come down to how the operating system runs your threads.

Regarding Daemon threads, a daemon is like a 'sub-thread' (or child thread as I like to think :) )  of a user thread.  This means it is linked/connected to a user Thread.  In your case it is linked to the main thread, when the main thread ends the daemon will die with it.  HOWEVER because you have another user Thread running (t2) the main method waits until that is finished.  If you were to comment out t2 like so:

```
//          Thread t2 = new Thread(d,"Non-Daemon"); 
            t1.start();
//          t2.start();
```

and then run your program you would likely find the daemon thread never runs because main ends too soon and when it exits takes the daemon thread with it.

**Priority Check**

Change your loop code statement to this:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ i 
                    + " [Proirity] " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
```

And you can see the priority for yourself.  Priority is scaled from 1 -10, when I ran it both t1 and t2 had priority 5 so netiher was lower than the other.